# How do I transform this angular distribution from CMS frame to lab frame?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, kinematics, elementary-particles

One can derive that the angular distribution of a 1 -> 2 + 3 decay process is given by:

\begin{equation}\frac{d\Gamma}{d\Omega} = \frac{1}{32\pi^2}\frac{|\boldsymbol{p}_2|}{M^2}|T_{fi}|^2\end{equation}

where $|\boldsymbol{p}_2| = |\boldsymbol{p}_3|$ is the momentum of the outgoing particle in the rest frame of the decay particle, M is the mass of the decay particle and $|T_{fi}|^2$ is the invariant Amplitude (also called M in most cases). This distribution depends on the Spin and Spin projection along an axis of the decay particle. As projection axis, one chooses the z-axis in the rest frame. Here is a picture [image]

My question now is, this distribution is given in the rest frame of particle 1, how do I transform this into the lab frame where the decay particle is moving (using a Lorentz Transformation along the z-axis, meaning that the z-axis is the same direction as the direction of flight in the lab frame).

Comment: Do you know the momentum of the original particle $\boldsymbol{p}_1$?

Comment: Its 0 since I am boosting from the rest frame of particle 1

Comment: ... do you know what it is in the lab frame? Otherwise there isn't the necessary information to do this transformation.