# Decay rate with specific helicity in rest frame and lab frame

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, kinematics, helicity, half-life

Consider a two-body decay, such as the pion decay: $\pi^+\to \mu^+ + \nu_\mu^{}$. In the Standard Model, as there only exits left-handed massless neutrinos, the helicities of final particles are known. For neutrino the helicity is always $h=-1$ and for anti-muon the helicity is always $h=+1$.

However, as neutrinos are massive with the discovery of the neutrino oscillation. Therefore, there should be different decay channels. More specifically, we have $\pi^+\to \mu^+(h=+1)+\nu_\mu^{}(h=+1)$ and $\pi^+\to \mu^+(h=-1)+\nu_\mu^{}(h=-1)$ in the rest frame of the pion.

Now, we boost the pion $\pi^+$ with a velocity $\beta$. Therefore, decay rates in the rest frame and in the lab frame are different, but the total decay rate can be transformed with the Lorentz transformation. However, for the decay channel with specific helicity for the daughter particles, the Lorentz boost will change the helicity, since it may affect the direction of velocity.

Now it comes the question, how to describe the transformation between the decay rate in the rest frame and that in the lab frame, with specific helicity? I think this is a pure kinematics problem, while I have not seen any note or books teaching this aspect.

p.s., the $|{\cal M}|^2$ should be Lorentz-invariant, thus the focus is only appearing at the phase-space part.
p.s.2. I found a similar question [How do I transform this angular distribution from CMS frame to lab frame?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/413563/378234). I think we are asking similar questions.